# Hibernate java.sql.SQLException: invalid schema name using embedded db

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm getting the following error while testing my application with an embedded db:

> java.sql.SQLException: invalid schema name: DOMAININSC1_

The query that I'm trying to do is this:

```
SELECT distinct d FROM DomainDO d left join fetch d.domainInscriptionProduct WHERE d.id IN (:listIds)
```

And DomainDO has the following relation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Domain_Registry")
public class DomainDO {

[...]

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "domainId")
    private Set<DomainInscriptionProductDO> domainInscriptionProduct = new HashSet<DomainInscriptionProductDO>(0);

[...]

}
```

The Hibernate translates the query to this:

```
select distinct domaindo0_.idt_domain_registry as idt1_1_0_, domaininsc1_.IDT_DOMAIN_INSCRIPTION_PRODUCT as IDT1_23_1_, domaindo0_.dat_creation as dat2_1_0_, domaindo0_.idt_master_domain as idt3_1_0_, domaindo0_.dat_expiration as dat4_1_0_, domaindo0_.nam_domain_extension as nam5_1_0_, domaindo0_.IDT_DOMAIN_PROMOTION as IDT6_1_0_, domaindo0_.idt_domain_partner_extension as idt7_1_0_, domaindo0_.idt_inscription as idt8_1_0_, domaindo0_.nam_domain as nam9_1_0_, domaindo0_.idt_domain_partner as idt10_1_0_, domaindo0_.dat_registry as dat11_1_0_, domaindo0_.cod_domain_registry_status as cod12_1_0_, domaindo0_.dat_updated as dat13_1_0_, domaininsc1_.DAT_CREATION as DAT2_23_1_, domaininsc1_.IDT_DOMAIN_REGISTRY as IDT3_23_1_, domaininsc1_.IDT_INSCRIPTION as IDT4_23_1_, domaininsc1_.FLG_MASTER_DOMAIN as FLG5_23_1_, domaininsc1_.IDT_PRODUCT as IDT6_23_1_, domaininsc1_.IDT_DOMAIN_REGISTRY as IDT3_1_0__, domaininsc1_.IDT_DOMAIN_INSCRIPTION_PRODUCT as IDT1_0__ from Domain_Registry domaindo0_, DOMAIN_INSCRIPTION_PRODUCT domaininsc1_ where domaindo0_.idt_domain_registry=domaininsc1_.IDT_DOMAIN_REGISTRY(+) and (domaindo0_.idt_domain_registry in (?))
```

I tried this on the database and it works properly, but when run with jUnit with the embedded database I receive the error shown.

I searched everywhere and couldn't find anything similiar.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Add the code of `DomainInscriptionProductDO` - it's hard to tell anything without seeing both sides of the link.

Comment: DomainInscriptionProductDO does not have a relation with DomainDO, it only have its fields.